# Blender 3.0 Bake Combined UvMap Border Lines Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I am new on bake system. I have a sink and want to bake texture but it is have a big problem. Baked texture uvmap border line seems on object. How can I solve this? I use default bake settings and Optix render.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the denoise filter, I guess it applies the filter before extending the capture result, that's why you see the black pixels on the edges.

[image: black stitching]

To fix this, first disable the denoise filter and bake the texture.

[image: baked with noise]

As you can see in the image, we now have noise in the baked texture. (denoise filter missing)
The next step is to go to the compositor and add the denoise node here, hit F12 to save the texture to disk.

[image: copositor nodes]

Reload the filtered texture and ready.

[image: result]

This happens in Blender 3.0.1, I guess they will fix it in future versions.
I hope it helps.